# Is every variety (defined as separated prevariety) a locally closed subset of some projective space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Hartshorne Ch1, variety is defined to be a affine, quasi-affine, projective or quasi-projective variety.

In Mumford's Red book, it was defined to be separated prevariety(gluing of a finite number of irreducible varieties).

Is every separated prevariety isomorphic to some variety defined as affine, quasi-affine, projective or quasi-projective variety?

Comment: Regarding your first sentence: note that Hartshorne changes his tune in Chapter II --- Remark 4.10.1 says "From now on we will use the word "variety" to mean "abstract variety" in the sense just defined." (Which is to say, the same as Mumford's definition.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: there is the famous Hironaka example of a non-projective complete variety in dimension 3. This is explained in Hartshorne: Appendix B, Example 3.4.1.